# Declaring pictureboxes as individual objects and changing their locations

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to declare multiple separate pictureboxes with different positions, backgroundcolors and tags. I would like to use the tags to refer to the pictureboxes in my code, to change and/or remove them individually.
How do I go about this?

I have attempted to create a separate class, meant for creating the same picturebox as a public static but encountered some issues with the `trbRed.Value` values, since they don't exist in that class. I am not sure if this solution would work for my cause, and neither do I have a clue on how to create the class either way.

This program uses drag and drop, and therefore uses the mousepositions
to create pictureboxes with different backcolors.

`picBlock` is declared earlier in the class with 
`PictureBox picBlock = new PictureBox();`.

```cs
private void myPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int mouseX = e.X / 25 + 1;
            int mouseY = (myPanel.Size.Height - e.Y) / 25 + 1;

            if (myPanel.BackgroundImage != null)
            {
                lblMousePos.Show();
                lblMousePos.Text = "pos (" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ")";
            }
        }

public void myPanel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    picBlock = new PictureBox
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, trbRed.Value, 
        trbGreen.Value, trbBlue.Value),

        Image = Image.FromFile("my picture here.png"),

        Size = new Size(25, 24),

        Location = new Point((mouseX - 1) * 25, 
        this.myPanel.Height - mouseY * 24),

        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,

        Tag = mouseX.ToString() + ", " + mouseY.ToString()
    };

    listX_pos.Add(mouseX);
    listY_pos.Add(mouseY);

    picBlock.MouseMove += picBlock_mousemove;
    picBlock.MouseDown += picBlock_mousedown;

    this.myPanel.Controls.Add(picBlock);
}

public void picBlock_mousedown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.myPanel.Controls.Remove(picBlock);
            for (int i = 0; i < listX_pos.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listX_pos[i] == ((picBlock.Location.X / 25) + 1) && listY_pos[i] == (this.myPanel.Location.Y - picBlock.Location.Y / 25) - 11)
                {
                    listX_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                    listY_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
//pcbPicture is a picturebox with the same content of "my picture here.png"
            picBlock.DoDragDrop(pcbPicture.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

public void picBlock_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myPanel.BackgroundImage != null)
            {
//a label to show the position of the mouse
                lblMousePos.Show();
                Point point = myPanel.PointToClient(MousePosition);
                int mouseX = point.X / 25 + 1;
                int mouseY = (myPanel.Size.Height - point.Y) / 25 + 1;
                lblMousePos.Text = "pos (" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ")";
            }
        }
```

I have no issues creating the pictureboxes, but can only change the position of the most recently created picturebox from `picBlock_mousemove` as well as `picBlock_mousedown` voids.
I want to be able to change the position for any of the created pictureboxes as well as their own controls (mousemove and mousedown).

Comment: My crystal ball says you use `picBlock` in your mouse move handler. Check if using the `sender` will make you happy (after it is cast to a PictureBox).

Comment: Which GUI techonlogy are you using/ I gues that winforms, am I right?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman .NET Framework 4.6.1 (winforms)

Comment: @rene my mouse move handler contains object sender, if that is what you mean. ´´´picBlock_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)´´´.
Did you perhaps mean that my declaration for picBlock earlier in the class should contain sender?

Comment: If you wil display us your mousemove/down handler, maybe we'll can help you.

Comment: You could use a function to search by tag: `Control CtlByTag(Control parent, string tag)
{
    var ctl = parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(x => x.Tag.ToString() == tag);
    return ctl.Any() ? ctl.First() : null;
}`  If it doesn't return null cast to PictureBox and use the result!. But: The MouseMove handler already knows which control triggered it, namely the `sender`..

Comment: @TaW It could be very simpler by making it an extension method and like `Control CtrlByTag(this Control parent, object tag) { return parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(c => tag.Equals(c)); }`

Answer (score 1):

As @rene  said, your problem is that in your `picBlock` mouse handlers, you refer to `picBlock`, which contains only the last image created.

The solution is in the event. Each event in .NET, has two properties, by convention: `object sender` and `System.EventArgs e`.

`e` is the more understable; It's a class drived from `System.EventArgs` (or itself) that contains some required information about the event: the pressed mouse button/keyboard key, mouse X and Y, and so on - any relevant information.

`sender` is less usable. It contains the object that triggered the event.

Why? Can't we access it directly, such as by member variable?

The answer is your (and similar) cases: we attach a single method to events of some objects, then we want to know on which element to work. For example, a simple example that pops up a messagebox every time you click a button, with it's content:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var btn = new Button
        {
            Text = "Button #" + i, Top = i * 50, Left = 0
        };
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

private void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Text); // Access the clicked button by `sender`
}
```

Returning to your question, use it like (you don't need a member variable `picBlock`):

```
private void myPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (myPanel.BackgroundImage != null)
        {
            lblMousePos.Show();
            lblMousePos.Text = "pos (" + (e.X / 25 + 1) + ", " + ((myPanel.Size.Height - e.Y) / 25 + 1) + ")";
        }
}

public void myPanel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var picBlock = new PictureBox
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, trbRed.Value, 
        trbGreen.Value, trbBlue.Value),

        Image = Image.FromFile("my picture here.png"),

        Size = new Size(25, 24),

        Location = new Point((mouseX - 1) * 25, 
        this.myPanel.Height - mouseY * 24),

        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,

        //Tag = musX.ToString() + ", " + musY.ToString()
        // You don't need the Tag property
    };

    picBlock.MouseMove += picBlock_mousemove;
    picBlock.MouseDown += picBlock_mousedown;

    this.myPanel.Controls.Add(picBlock);
}

public void picBlock_mousedown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        var picBlock = (PictureBlock)sender;
        this.panelSpel.Controls.Remove(picBlock);
        for (int i = 0; i < listX_pos.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listX_pos[i] == ((picBlock.Location.X / 25) + 1) && listY_pos[i] == (this.myPanel.Location.Y - picBlock.Location.Y / 25) - 11)
            {
                listX_pos.RemoveAt(i);
                listY_pos.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        //pcbPicture is a picturebox with the same content of "my picture here.png"
        picBlock.DoDragDrop(pcbPicture.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

public void picBlock_mousemove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        var picBlock = (PictureBlock)sender;
        if (myPanel.BackgroundImage != null)
        {
            //a label to show the position of the mouse
            lblMousePos.Show();
            Point point = myPanel.PointToClient(MousePosition);
            int mouseX = point.X / 25 + 1;
            int mouseY = (myPanel.Size.Height - point.Y) / 25 + 1;
            lblMousePos.Text = "pos (" + musX + ", " + musY + ")";
        }
}
```